# Postgres connection should be always on? or connect before running each query?

Tags: postgresql, connection

I am debating if I should keep my postgres connection always on, and check/re-connect before running query. Or I should connect it before run each query and close the connection as soon as it is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the postgres connection string has a bunch of setting for the connection pooling, for example:

User ID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;
Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;

So in my code, I can just close the connection after the command finished execution. But behind the scene, the connection is actually still alive and stored in the connection pool to be used again.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the *Postgres* server isn't totally jammed with connections (i.e. this is not an app that will be creating a gigantic number of perpetual connections), I don't think it's a problem to maintain the connection. I would also recommend checking the connection and handling reconnects prior to each query however. Many libraries offer ways to do this. For example, with *MyBatis* (*Java*), you can have it issue a test query each time, which can be specified. I use the lightweight `SELECT 1` for this.

I would say the key thing to consider is to keep the connection *idle in transaction* for as little time as possible, as when that happens, it can have a variety of different impacts on performance (such as slowing down other queries, preventing  high-turnover tables from being vacuumed in a timely manner, etc.). This is not to say that any time spent in *idle in transaction* is automatically bad, but it should be considered and minimized where possible. (e.g. if you have some calculations that are going several minutes to run, make sure to either `commit` or `rollback` prior to doing those (which one would depend on context).

If you're doing a bunch of `SELECT`s, and don't have anything you need to `commit`, I would recommend doing a `rollback` to help keep the *idle in transaction* states to a minimum.